# Prove that John is not a light sleeper

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Define each sentence in terms of CNF. Prove that John is not a light sleeper.

```
(1): All wolves howl.
(2): Anyone who has casts as pets will not have mice.
(3): Anyone who is a light sleeper can't live near anything that howls.
(4): John either has cats or lives near wolves.
(5): If John is a light sleeper, John has mice.
```

> $Wolf(x): x$ is a wolf
>
> $Howl(x): x$ howls
>
> $Have(x,y): x$ has y
>
> $Cat(x): x$ is a cat
>
> $Mouse(x): x$ is a mouse
>
> $LS(x): x$ is a light sleeper
>
> $Live(x,y): x$ lives near y

I began by writing each sentence in terms of quantifiers:

> (1): $\forall x(Wolf(x)\rightarrow Howl(x))$
>
> (2): $\forall x\forall y\forall z(Have(x,Cat(y)) \rightarrow \neg Have(x,Mouse(z))$
>
> (3): $\forall x \forall y((\neg LS(x) \wedge Howls(y)) \rightarrow \neg Live(x,y))$
>
> (4): $\exists x, \exists y(Have(Frank,Cat(x))\vee Live(Frank,Wolf(y)))$
>
> (5): $\exists (LS(Frank)\rightarrow Have(Frank,Mouse(x)))$

So my first question is whether these quantifier sentences are correct. My second question is how we can take these to CNF. I understand that something like $x\rightarrow y$ can turn into $\neg x \vee \neg y$, but I don't see how we can eliminate quantifiers altogether. Can someone perhaps show me how this is done with one of the quantifier sentences?

Comment: I think you don't have to set all these functions which in my opinion does not make sense. and also we have :$P \implies Q$ can turn into $\neg P \vee Q$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP is gone, it is very specific, and the answer is not stellar.

Comment: @Lord_Farin None of which is a valid close reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints :**

Let P denotes an animal, and A denotes a person:

> (1): $P$ is a wolf  $\implies$ P howl.
>
> (2): $A$ has cats as pets $\implies $ A don't have mice.
>
> (3): $A$ is a light sleeper $\implies$ $A$ don't live near anything that howls.
>
> (4): John  has cats **[XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)**  John  lives near wolves. [ this one can be expressed as : (John  has cats **AND**  John  doesn't live near wolves) **OR** (John  don't have cats **AND** John  lives near wolves  ]
>
> (5):  John is a light sleeper $\implies$ John has mice.

begin with (5) and do a proof by contradiction.

**Update :**

by contradiction let us suppose that John is a light sleeper.
by (**5**) this implies that John has mice.
by (**2**) [ its Contraposition] this implies that John don't have cats.
by (**4**)   this implies that John  lives near wolves. 
by the (**3**) [ its Contraposition] **AND** (**1**) : this implies that John is not a light sleeper ( and this is the contradiction because we supposed that  John is a light sleeper)

Hence, John is not a light sleeper

Comment: How do we write this for my sentences? Can you just say "Let $P$ denote and animal and $A$ a person" (1): Wolf(P)->Howl(P)?

Comment: For example, in the 2nd one, can we write: $Have(A,Cat(P))\rightarrow \neg Have(A,mouse(P))$?

Comment: How does the proof by contradiction work? If we start with assuming John is a light sleeper, we don't end up with saying he is not a light sleeper...

Comment: @JennParker the problem with your sentences is that they are not rigorous, they are sometimes even senseless, for example Have(A,mouse(P)) = A has ( P is a mouse) !!. and I do not see why resort to such notations when you can express with a clear language instead. $--$ for P and A it's just an intuitive separation, you can keep P only as humane can be considered as an animal :) -- I will update my answer to include my full reflexion on your question.